# How to create an array in a class created in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object

```
class Student{
public:
    int sNumber;
    int wantedCoursesNumber;
    int qStudent;
    int courselist;
    Student(int cN,int qS,int i){
        this->sNumber = i;
        this->wantedCoursesNumber = cN;
        this->qStudent = qS;
        this->courselist = new int[cN];
    }
```

when i create this class,it gives the error 
"invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]"
for courselist.I just want to create in every student object an array that has the size of cN
can anyone help me , i'm new in c++

Comment: Should be `int* courselist;`

Comment: courselist is of type `int` it needs to be a pointer of ints. And you need to save the array size somewhere, otherwise you will probably segfault.

Comment: Thx a lot what  is the difference between int* and int ?

Comment: @McOne, `int` is just an ìnteger, `int*` is a *pointer* to an integer.

Comment: vector vector vector, please do yourself a favor: use `std::vector`.

Comment: what is pointer anyway, I know i should search for this but when I searched, it seemed complicated,is there a simple explaination for pointers in c++ ? Is there any difference between int* courselist and int *courselist ? because it compiled both ways.

Comment: Take the pointer answers with extra caution. Neither mention the Rule of Three. Anyway, there are tons of pointer resources and also tons of vector resources.

Comment: If you dont know about pointers then (a) read up on them, and (b) dont ever ever use them. Look at the vector answer below.

Comment: I thought like since I know what size the list will be , it would be faster to use arrays when I want to reach an element in the list but I might have thought wrong.I have a project to do in 2 days , I didn't want to waste time by learning pointers thinking that it would have most of my time but I know how to use vectors, should  I use vector or array in case I know what the size is at the beginning,because the time of program is also important in project.Btw how am I going to mark these comments as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Student{
public:
int sNumber;
int wantedCoursesNumber;
int qStudent;
int *courselist;
Student(int cN,int qS,int i){
    this->sNumber = i;
    this->wantedCoursesNumber = cN;
    this->qStudent = qS;
    this->courselist = new int[cN];
}
```

change veriable to pionter

Answer (score 6):

Avoid the memory leak operator—aka `new[]`. Instead, C++ has a data type called [`std::vector<int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which allows you to create arrays of integers of dynamic size.

```
#include <vector>

class Student {
public:
    int sNumber;
    int wantedCoursesNumber;
    int qStudent;
    std::vector<int> courselist;

    Student(int cN, int qS, int i)
        : sNumber(i)
        , wantedCoursesNumber(cn)
        , qStudent(qS)
        , courseList(cN) {

    }
};
```

Since you’re new (pun not intended) to C++, I highly recommend [*The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @OneOfOne, Idk about proper.  Vectors have overhead.  It would be nice if this post mentioned/explained RAII, initialization lists or destructors.  These are skills that need to be learned even if your good at avoiding there use.

Answer (score -1):

You are assigning an `int` array to `courselist`, which fails because `courselist` is declared as `int`, not `int*` (a pointer to `int`). Try declaring the variable like this:

`int* courselist;`

Comment: VLAs are not allowed in structs

Comment: @Tim thanks for pointing that out, I'm coding Java lazily while browsing SoF and getting things mixed up!